# Want to know the WCF Messaging architecture details

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding

I have not worked on the WSE/ASMX webs services and I am learning WCF now.

I want to know how the messages are transferred between WCF client and service? How do Data Contract and Message Contract, Service Behaviors etc. work? How do they affect in creating client proxies and SOAP messages to and from the service?

In short, I am searching for the WCF messaging architecture. Some days back i had found the detailed architecture on MSDN but now unfortunately, I am unable to find it.

Can anyone please point me to relevant article/blog etc.?

Comment: I found the answer to my question. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374127/want-to-know-the-wcf-messaging-architecture-details/5374269#5374269

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the article i was looking for.

[Data Transfer Architectural Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347789.aspx) is the article i was looking for.

All the articles related to WCF data transfer and serialization features can be found under 
[Data Transfer And Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730035.aspx)